# Error handling not working asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I have the following code for handling my errors

Global.asax.cs in Application_Error

```
Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
if (exception != null)
{
    //Log the error
}
```

However I also have custom error pages which I redirect to above as well as from the web.config - I did this because it seems that Application_Error does not catch all errors that occur?

So in my error page on Page_Load I have this code

```
Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();                
string exInnerExp = "";
if (exception != null)
{
    exInnerExp = exception.InnerException.ToString();
    //Log error
}
```

This never works? I have no idea why, any help with this is much appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**
In my web.config I have the following code:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
   <error redirect="http://www.example.com/errorpages/404.aspx" statusCode="404" />
   <error redirect="http://www.example.com/errorpages/siteerror.aspx" statusCode="500" />
</customErrors>
```

As well as

```
<httpErrors>
   <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errorpages/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errorpages/siteerror.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

**EDIT**

Initially I though that Application_Error was not being hit, but then I found a piece of code which was only actually running if Server.GetLastError() was not null. So now my problem has changed slightly, Server.GetLastError() is null in the Application_Error event. For example of where this can happen:

I have a built project which works perfectly, not if I go to a UserControl and change a asp:TextBox's ID then the page will not load and throws and error, this error is not caught.

Comment: What you have on web.config on `customErrors` ?

Comment: I can not see anything problematic here. Maybe some code is clear your errors. Did your site hit the `Application_Error` ?

Comment: @Aristos please see my Edit, it is being hit but there is no error.

Comment: try `<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">` to see whats change.